# OAuth client - How to change javascript origin from http to https on request?

Tags: http, https, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, redirect

On a project in google cloud platform I filled out the OAuth consent screen and created an OAuth 2.0 client ID with Javascript origin being https://example.com (my site). Then when I tried to login with a google id, 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error was raised saying the Javascript origin in the request http://example.com does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Adding http://~ to the origin list made the login possible but http was not allowed in order to make use of sensitive scopes of user data, which is necessary for my project. I think all problems will resolve if I could send the request by https. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify this comment: `I think all problems will resolve if I could send the request by https`? All requests must be via HTTPS except for localhost. I don't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm focusing on the difference between https and http. For sensitive scopes only https javascript origins are allowed but my code is requesting by http.

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh, accessing my site by https:// example.com resolved that issue, but how to make the browser access the site on https by default? When I enter example.com, it seems that it uses http on default.

Comment: The origin can be http or https. The OAuth 2.0 callback must be https unless you are testing with localhost. What you are seeing is scopes that Google interprets as sensitive and will require your application to be approved. Some scopes will not be approved (add these scopes to your question). You just posted another comment and I don't understand what you are asking.